# R dataframe (>2 columns) to named list

Tags: r

I am trying to get a data frame row to a named list where the dataframe column header values become the keys of the named list.

Transposing the row seemed like a good idea, but then trying to coerce this to a list doesn't have the desired effect.

My attempt so far:

```
t(df[1, ]) # seems useful
list(t(df[1, ])) # but this doesn't have the desired effect
```

Reproducible:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

Desired effect for first row:

```
list(n = 2, 
     s = aa,
     b = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.list`

```
as.list(df[1, ])

#$n
#[1] 2

#$s
#[1] "aa"

#$b
#[1] TRUE
```

**data**

```
df = data.frame(n, s, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Weird, I tried that and it didn't work before, but now it does. Thanks!

Comment: nice solution with `as.list`, + 1

Comment: Ah, but this solution doesn't work if there are empty values in the list. The header becomes "NA" even though there is a value for the header.

Comment: What do you mean by empty values? It works for `NA` values i.e `n = c(NA, 3, 5)`

Comment: Just getting an example (and yes). Although my NAs have been rendered as <NA> sometimes

Comment: It's with NULLs, sorry. When I subset certain rows with missing values, I get something like this: test <- data.frame(
label = "welcome",
page_type = "audio_page",
other = NULL,
stimulus_corpus = NULL)

Comment: Obviously you can't create a df from that (you'll get an error), but this is what I get if there is missing data and when your method doesn't work for a named list.

Comment: yes, length of `NULL` is 0. Usually it is better to test which values are `NULL` with `is.null` and replace them with `NA` so that length is maintained.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `unclass`, e.g.,

```
> unclass(df[1,])
$n
[1] 2

$s
[1] aa
Levels: aa bb cc

$b
[1] TRUE

attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1
```